# how to get values in dropdownlist bounded within a gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding, drop-down-menu

Inside gridview  a dropdownlist is there

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="quantity" runat="server" DataValueField="ItemID" DataTextField="Quantity">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

for each itemid there is some numeric value in Quantity field of Database Table
i want that this dropdown must contain the values `from 1 to quantity.DataTextField` for all the items present in the cart

the procedure by which gridview is bound is

```
create proc [dbo].[prcItemsinCart](@CartID int)
as
    select distinct ct.Price,ct.Quantity,ct.ItemID,
           ct.CartID,ct.ProductID,p.ProductName,
           isnull((  select top 1 convert(varchar,PhotoID,10) + '.' + ExtName
                 from ProductPhoto 
                 where ProductID = ct.ProductID ),'NoImage.jpg'
           ) as Product, 
           ( Select Price*Quantity 
             from CartItems 
             where CartID=ct.CartID and ProductID=ct.ProductID
           ) as SubTotal
    from CartItems as ct 
    inner join ProductInfo as p on ct.ProductID=p.ProductID 
    inner join ProductPhoto as pp on ct.ProductID=pp.ProductID 
    where ct.CartID=@CartID
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a `HiddenField` in the `TemplateField` to hold the CartID, I will use the CartID in the code. My Markup should look like:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
    <ItemTemplate>  
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnId" runat="server" value='<%#Eval("CartID") %>'></asp:HiddenField>                            
        <asp:DropDownList ID="quantity" runat="server" DataValueField="ItemID" DataTextField="Quantity">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In the code, in GridView's RowDataBound I am finding the `DropDownList` and `HiddenField`, running a Sql Query to bring my expected data, and binding them to my `DropdownList`:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DropDownList quantity = e.Row.FindControl("quantity") as DropDownList;
        HiddenField hdnId = e.Row.FindControl("hdnId") as HiddenField;

        if (quantity != null && hdnId != null)
        {
            string queryString = String.Format("SELECT ItemID, Quantity FROM  CartItems  WHERE CartID= {0}", hdnId.Value);

            //MyConnectionString is your connection string in web.config
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ToString()))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                quantity.DataSource = reader;
                quantity.DataValueField = "ItemID";
                quantity.DataTextField = "Quantity";
                quantity.DataBind();               
            }
        }        

    }
}
```